# Open a CSV in server

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app and I need to open csv in the server. I don't need the input external. In this code for example where I can write read csv?

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 10, max = 500, value = 100)
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do with the csv-file? How should it be used in the shiny app?

Comment: Yes! After the upload, I need to use it

Comment: Then you should put it in the server function, e.g. `df <- read.csv("file") output$distPlot_df <- renderPlot({
  hist(df$x)
})`

Comment: after: server <- function(input, output) { , right?